# Android unable to start activity, error inflating class?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-activity, runtimeexception

I'm new to android. I have some java knowledge, and I'm using Eclipse. 
At the moment I'm trying to display a map within a tab, and am looking at tutorials/code to help me. :)

I've seen a few questions asking about this error, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, still. 
I'm using code from here: http://vkroz.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/programming-android-%E2%80%93-map-view-within-tab-view/

Am I just missing something obvious?

The value of the runtime exception e:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: ... android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Line 24 is just `</LinearLayout>`

The whole of main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/emptylayout1" android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Details Details Details Details"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout> 
</TabHost>
```

The rest of my code is the same as linked, but I'll paste it here too.

MapInTabActivity.java

```
package com.test.mapintab;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MapInTabActivity extends TabActivity {

    TabHost mTabHost;
    FrameLayout mFrameLayout;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTabHost = getTabHost();
        TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Map");
        Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MapInTabActivity.class);
        tabSpec.setContent(i);

        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Details").setContent(R.id.textview2));
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }

}
```

MapTabView.java:

```
package com.test.mapintab;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MapTabView extends MapActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.maptabview);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
        return false;
    }

}
```

maptabview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/maptablayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"            
        android:apiKey="0HRMcD5o6WrBVhmwbWpeyeavZ67PXWOvJeeCx2g"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.mapintab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MapInTabActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity android:name=".MapTabView" android:label="@string/mapview_name">
           <intent-filter>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED"></category>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the rest of logcat (I think the important part was the bit I pointed out at the top, but maybe there's something else I don't know about).

```
02-05 09:49:21.239: W/dalvikvm(357): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivit
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix this:

`Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>`

Also for your emulator are you use the **Google APIs** version? The other versions do **NOT** have this library.

**UPDATE**

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: I am using a Google APIs avd. :) 
How should I fix line 24? I don't see what is wrong with it.

Comment: I did that example no problem, thanks. :D 
Maybe it would be better if I tried to make a map within a tab myself instead of borrowing this code.

Comment: its a view, it doesn't matter.

Comment: A Mapview is a View. Meaning that it is infact a view, and as such view content is attached to a Tab, so they are infact the same, and as such doen't matter. A view is a view.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the example that link you are following. Its working fine in my end. Your Manifest file says, you have not declared the MapTabView activity in the Manifest file. Use this in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MapTabView" android:label="@string/mapview_name">
   <intent-filter>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED"></category>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Your code runs without errors, but doesn't display the map, just a grid. And I can't see where mine differs from yours. I'll keep looking and let you know if/when I work it out. :)

Comment: Okey ! Map will come just Change the MapView API code with your Map API code.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you borrow code you should make sure you understand all of it, because a lot can go wrong. It seems like the problem is with your intent. You have:

```
Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
```

Usually intents are tied to activity contexts not application contexts so I would check that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into intents, cause I don't really know much about them.