# mapView deprecated method getZoomControls?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, zooming, android-mapview

I'm trying to get the default zoom controls to show on a google mapView. 
I was looking at [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) code. But getZoomControls() is deprecated.

I'm trying to use setBuiltInZoomControls instead, but am getting errors;

When I debug, the exception is;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.maptab2/com.test.maptab2.MapTabView}: java.lang.NullPointerException


02-05 09:49:21.239: W/dalvikvm(357): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 09:49:22.616: E/AndroidRuntime(357): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.mapintab/com.test.mapintab.MapInTabActivit
```

Line 18 is mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

My map is being displayed within a tab, which I do like this in my main class (which deals with the tabs- the contents each being their own classes);

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MapTabView.class);

TabHost.TabSpec spec;

spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("tab1");
spec.setContent(i);
spec.setIndicator("Map");
getTabHost().addTab(spec);
```

Here's my code:

MapTabView.java

```
package com.test.maptab2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MapTabView extends MapActivity {

    MapView mapView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.maptabview);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.layout.maptabview);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
        return false;
    }

}
```

maptabview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/maptablayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Actual map -->
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0HRMcD5o6WrBVhmwbWpeyeavZ67PXWOvJeeCx2g"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've just realised this is the same error as one I'm getting here: [Android unable to start activity, error inflating class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148400/android-unable-to-start-activity-error-inflating-class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be enough to achieve what you want.

```
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.historymapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Then you don't need to explicitly place your ZoomControls  in the XML, nor to reference it in your java code

Comment: This gives me a nullPointerException at line 18, which is mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
I'll edit the question with the details

Comment: Try repleacing findViewById(R.layout.maptabview); in your XML with findViewById(R.layout.mapview); (the actual id set in your XML)

Comment: 'cannot be resolved or is not a field' I thought that R.layout stored the layout file references (ie main and any additionals), not the elements within them?